# Ecto displays parsed query but not search results

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Here is what I get when I search for a database record using Ecto:

```
jxxmbp:lookup carlson$ ./lookup --title foo

02:55:19.029 [debug] QUERY OK source="notes" db=2.3ms decode=2.2ms queue=45.1ms
SELECT n0."id", n0."title", n0."content" FROM "notes" AS n0 WHERE (n0."title" = $1) ["foo"]
```

but I want the records found, not the equery.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def process({:title, arg}) do
    Lookup.Note |> Ecto.Query.where(title: ^arg) |> Lookup.Repo.all
  end
```

Comment: The record with title "foo" and content "bar" exists in the database

Comment: As in you want to print the records to the screen? You probably want to use `IO.inspect/2` somewhere in order to print the results. Or maybe look into Elixir's [`Logger`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html) module.

Comment: Justin, thanks so much!  I appended `|> IO.inspect` to the body of the relevant function and I am getting what I need for the moment.  I've been working with Elixir for two days now and LOVE IT!